# How to multiply all the components of a skip length by the same number?

Tags: expl3, arithmetic

I am looking for a way to simply multiply all the components in a skip expression ( the natural length plus the plus-length minus the minus-length ) by the same number. I've tried some examples in my MWE below without success. Of course, I could just create 3 different dimen expressions, then multiply each dimen expression by a number, and then input each result into the skip expression, but I'm looking for an easier, more convenient solution. In my MWE, `\skip_show:N` displays only the natural length when it doesn't produce an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip { 36pt plus 18pt minus 12pt }
\skip_const:Nn \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
{
    %\fp_eval:n { 0.8333 } \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip
    %\c_mymodule_myskipi_skip * \fp_eval:n { 0.8333 }
    %\skip_eval:n {  \fp_eval:n { 0.8333 } \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip  }
    \skip_eval:n {  \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip * \fp_eval:n { 0.8333 }  }
}
\skip_show:N \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the primitive level you want `\multiply` or `\glueexpr`

```
\baselineskip=20pt plus 5pt minus 2pt

\showthe\baselineskip

\multiply\baselineskip by 2

\showthe\baselineskip

\baselineskip=\glueexpr(\baselineskip * 10)\relax

\showthe\baselineskip


\bye
```

Produces

```
> 20.0pt plus 5.0pt minus 2.0pt.
l.4 \showthe\baselineskip
                         
? 
> 40.0pt plus 10.0pt minus 4.0pt.
l.8 \showthe\baselineskip
                         
? 
> 400.0pt plus 100.0pt minus 40.0pt.
l.12 \showthe\baselineskip
```

`expl3` uses `\glueexpr` so:

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip { 36pt plus 18pt minus 12pt }
\skip_const:Nn \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
{
    \skip_eval:n { ( \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip * 25 )/30  }
}
\skip_show:N \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

producing

```
> \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip=30.0pt plus 15.0pt minus 10.0pt.
<recently read> }
                 
l.8 \skip_show:N \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
                                          
?
```

or more simply (as evaluation is implicit)

```
\documentclass{article}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\skip_const:Nn \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip { 36pt plus 18pt minus 12pt }
\skip_const:Nn \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
{
     ( \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip * 25 )/30  
}
\skip_show:N \c_mymodule_myskipii_skip
\ExplSyntaxOff
\begin{document}
text
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless I'm mistaken, it seems like this method doesn't work for numbers with decimal places.

Comment: hence 25/30  (which is anyway more accurate for the value I assume you wanted than 0.8333 ) @User23456234

Comment: Maybe I should have used a different example other than 0.83333. The issue is that (1) not all numbers with decimals convert nicely into a ratio of two integers and (2) I want to be able to use floating points directly for more straightforward code. Anyways, if there isn't an easy solution to this issue, I can always do it the hard way or write myself a macro for future use.

Comment: @User23456234 it would be easy to write a macro to get from 0.8333 to `( \c_mymodule_myskipi_skip /10000  ) * 8333`